# Get post content by ID

Tags: posts

How can I get a post's content by post id? I tried `get_page('ID');` to show content but it does not work.

Comment: Downvotes as you did not even try to read the docs on `get_page()`. It has been deprecited a very long time ago. Also, there are an unlimited amount of resources on site regarding this issue, even google has tons of info on this

Answer (score 19):

You can do it multiple ways. Following are best two ways.

```
$post_id = 5// example post id
$post_content = get_post($post_id);
$content = $post_content->post_content;
echo do_shortcode( $content );//executing shortcodes
```

Another method

```
$content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
echo do_shortcode( $content );//executing shortcodes
```

After Pieter Goosen suggestion on `apply_filters`.

You can use `apply_filters` if you wanted the content to be filtered by other plugins. So this eliminates the need to use `do_shortcode`

Example

```
$post_id = 5// example post id
$post_content = get_post($post_id);
$content = $post_content->post_content;
echo apply_filters('the_content',$content);
 //no need to use do_shortcode, but content might be filtered by other plugins.
```

If you don't want to allow other plugins to filter this content and need shortcode function then go with `do_shortcode`.

If you don't want shortcode too then just play with the `post_content`.

Comment: Just wonder why you are using `do_shortcode`

Comment: Hi thanks for asking. @PieterGoosen As we are getting the `raw content` of post. Any shortcode embedded in the post won't be processed. so we are doing that by ourself with `do_shortcode`

Comment: A better way would be to use `apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );`, this way, all filters that are applied to `the_content()` like `wpautop` and the shortcode handler, is applied to `$content`. ;-). Note the plural `filters`

Comment: Yes, using `apply_filters` instead of `do_shortcode` make sense. But using `apply_filter` is purely based on their environment decision. Let me update my answer too. Thank you so much for your care on community @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 0):

I'll just leave here another hacky ugly way that you may find useful sometimes. Of course methods which use API calls are always preferred (get_post(), get_the_content(), ...).

```
global $wpdb;
$post_id = 123; // fill in your desired post ID
$post_content_raw = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "select post_content from $wpdb->posts where ID = %d",
        $post_id
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = 23; // add the ID of the page where the zero is
$p = get_page($id);
$t = $p->post_title;
echo '<h3>'.apply_filters('post_title', $t).'</h3>'; // the title is here wrapped with h3
echo apply_filters('the_content', $p->post_content);
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

By using `get_page('ID')`.

```
$page_id = 123;  //Page ID
$page_data = get_page($page_id); 
$title = $page_data->post_title; 
$content = $page_data->post_content;
```

Comment: Downvoted as you really did not even tried to read the documentation. `get_page()` is depreciated